# Python: differences between tempfile.mkdtemp and tempfile.TemporaryDirectory

Tags: python, temporary-files

I need to create a temp directory that will house another named directory and subfiles. In the end the named directory and subfiles will be appended to a tarball and the temp directory can be removed. Was initially going to use [`mkdtemp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) but it looks like the [`TemporaryDirectory()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) method removes itself? Can someone explain the differences.

Comment: The last sentence of the docs is pretty clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct in that the only real difference is that `TemporaryDirectory` will delete itself when it is done. It will let you do something like:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dir:
   do_stuff_with(dir)
```

when you leave the scope of the `with`, the temporary directory will be deleted. With `mkdtemp`, you would need to do that manually.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation of 
[tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory):

> This function creates a temporary
>   directory using mkdtemp() (the
>   supplied arguments are passed directly
>   to the underlying function). The
>   resulting object can be used as a
>   context manager (see With Statement
>   Context Managers). On completion of
>   the context (or destruction of the
>   temporary directory object), the newly
>   created temporary directory and all
>   its contents are removed from the
>   filesystem.

Comment: Feel free to downvote me if you won't read the last sentence. The last sentence explains the asked question very clearly.

Comment: I don't remember reading any user requirements during SO registration that required I be of a certain level of proficiency with programming or development. Not all of us do this for a living nor should such be assumed. I'm merely asking for someone to further explain what's documented "clearly" to some.

Comment: So with mkdtemp a dirname is returned to be used. How do I create a subdir using TemporaryDirectory and write files to it. Do I use the TemporaryDirectory object as if it was a dirname? The necessary back information that you are not even questioning doesn't exist for some of us.